# WPF Bing Map Not Displayed Correctly

Tags: wpf, dictionary, user-controls

when i put `MapControl` in the `UserControl` it's displayed like this !!!

[image: Image from MapControl]

but when i put it in a `window` control everything looks fine
where is the problem??

```
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly= Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
```

```
<m:Map x:Name="myMap" ZoomLevel="12" CredentialsProvider="My Key" Mode="Aerial" Center="21.294485, 40.422371"></m:Map>
```

Comment: @Clemens I added the code, note that the same code is working in the wiindow control

Comment: Sorry dude, for me both ways are working fine. My `UserControl` only contains the code you have posted and is working fine. Maybe you could post a bit more code of your `UserControl`, if there is any.

Comment: Judging by the comments, you might need to post more code. It could be an issue with something else that is inadvertently causing the map to look funny. Without more code, there's no way to tell.